# Aframe Mobile Device Motion Not Detected

Tags: mobile-safari, aframe

On my iPhone and android devices I am only able to move the scene along the  x axis and only by touching and dragging the scene. Previously I was able to actually move my phone to look around the scene. The issue is present on both the examples I create and those on the aframe.io homepage.

I’m using an iPhone7 with software version 12.3.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Chrome and Safari now ship with devicemotion events disabled by default. The user has to enable manually on settings:

- `chrome://flags/#enable-generic-sensor` in Chrome
- `Settings -> Safari -> Motion & Orientation Access` in Safari iOS

Content also must be served over `https`.

More info on: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3976